# Not getting these errors in VSCode with TypeScript any more: "getStaticProps" is not a valid Next.js entry export value

Tags: next.js, next.js13, app-router

I am migrating a page from `pages` router to the new `app` router, so I just moved and renamed the file. This is when the error was expected and did first show up.

However, after a bit of working, I suddenly don't receive the errors any more.

What made the errors appear in the first place?
Is it some extension or configuration?
**How can I get them back?**

Note that I have a `next dev` command running and I do get these errors in the console still, just not in the VSCode IDE.